# Jquery jumping to top page on .click

Tags: jquery, click

I have a long list of inputs with a click function attached. This is bringing me back to the top of the page each time I click it

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function () { 
var name = $(this).attr("name");
if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:eq(1)')[0].checked) {
    $('label[name="' + name + '"]:eq(1)').addClass('nostate');
    $('label[name="' + name + '"]').removeClass('selected');
}
else {
    $('label[name="' + name + '"]').removeClass('nostate selected');
    if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:eq(0)')[0].checked) {
        $('label[name="' + name + '"]:eq(0)').addClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $('label[name="' + name + '"]:eq(2)').addClass('selected');
    }
}

});
```

I've tried

```
function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
```

and

```
return false;
```

But they didn't work I assume it's because there are `input`'s running down the whole page.

**Note:**

The reason I have it listening to the whole document, is because I have a second query which appends additional inputs and my click listener would work correctly when I clicked on the appended inputs. I assume this is because the click listener is bound to the `input`'s as the page loads

Also, there is no `href=""` on the click.

Comment: Is the url changing? Like having something appended to it after the hash sign? http://www.example.com/url#something/wrong-here

Comment: @motanelu no definitely not. I mean't to add in that point I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please so that we can see the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cutting out as much code as possible to create a minimal/comlete/verifiable example and going through the CSS I discovered it was caused by the positional hiding of radio buttons.

```
input[name^="state"][type="radio"] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

I changed it to

```
input[name^="state"][type="radio"] {
   display:none;
   //position: absolute;
   //top: -9999px;
   //left: -9999px;
}
```

and this did the trick.